How to sign in RingCentral Embedded widget in my Angular application?
I am working on Angular project with RingCentral embedded widget.
I have obtained the accessToken and refreshToken for the RingCentral account in the backend and received them in frontend (Angular application).
And my Angular application includes the RingCentral embedded widget using following JavaScript codes in the index.html.
        <script>
            (function() {
              var rcs = document.createElement("script");
              var clientId = "<MY CLIENT ID>";
              rcs.src = "https://apps.ringcentral.com/integration/ringcentral-embeddable/latest/adapter.js?"+"clientId="+clientId;
              var rcs0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
              rcs0.parentNode.insertBefore(rcs, rcs0);
            })();
          </script>

Then, after running the Angular application, it requires signing in to use RingCentral. So I need to automatically sign in to RingCentral using the accessToken and refreshTokken.

loadRingCentralWidget() {
    const clientId = '<MY CLIENT ID>';
    const accessToken = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';
    const refreshToken = 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN';
    const expiresIn = 3600; 

    (window as any).addEventListener('load', () => {
      (window as any).RCC.init({
        appServer: 'https://platform.ringcentral.com',
        clientId: clientId,
        authorize: () => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           
            resolve({
              token_type: 'Bearer',
              access_token: accessToken,
              refresh_token: refreshToken,
              expires_in: expiresIn,
            });
          });
        },
        refreshToken: () => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          
            fetch('YOUR_BACKEND_REFRESH_ENDPOINT', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                refresh_token: refreshToken
              })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
              resolve({
                token_type: 'Bearer',
                access_token: data.access_token,
                refresh_token: data.refresh_token,
                expires_in: data.expires_in,
              });
            })
            .catch(error => reject(error));
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

After authorize method, you'll need to use refreshToken method to handle the token refresh logic, which involves making request to your backend to get new access token using new refresh token.

Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.
